# Android how to write a pdf file to byteArrayBody to send it to server

Tags: android, http-post

I use following code fragment for image sending. And what should be done for sending DOC, mp4 files etc.

```
         MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity;

        String URL = "My server url";

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         Bitmap   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, byteArrayOutputStream); 
            byte[] byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            //String strData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT); // I have no idea why Im doing this
            ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(byteData, "image"); // second parameter is the name of the image (//TODO HOW DO I MAKE IT USE THE IMAGE FILENAME?)

            // send the package
            multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);


            webclient.getResponceFromWebService(URL, multipartEntity);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above code you mentioned works perfectly for images although there is only two line of code that can achieve what you want to do

```
    File f = new File("YOUR FILE PATH GOES HERE");
    byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f);
```

and this is your code adjust these two line of codes mentioned above anywhere with file Path

```
    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.amd);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


    ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(byteData, "image");

    // send the package
    multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    multipartEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);
```